# Не получается добавить изображение на JSP страницу

Tags: java-ee, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mastercomputer" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/images" cache-period="10000"/>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

**JSP**

```
<section class="content">
    <h2>Лучшие предложения</h2>
    <c:forEach var="note" items="${list}" >
        <div class="bestDeals">
            <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/Acer ES1-531.jpeg"/>" alt="Foto NoteBook" style="width: 150px;height:150px"/>
            <p>${note.name}</p>
            <p>${note.price}</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Купить" />
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</section>
```

Помогите разобраться где ошибка.

Comment: В том что вы неправильно используете [`mvc:resources`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources). Если судить по URL, то вам достаточно только первого варианта: `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`. **PS**. `Acer ES1-531.jpeg` хорошие программисты не используют пробелы. :)

Comment: Точно!!!! все заработало! Спасибо